# How to repeat a code when an exception is detected in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, exception, user-input

I have this class "ScanInput":

```java
public final class ScanInput {

    public String outputS;
    public int outputI;

    public ScanInput() {
    }

    public final void scanInt(String text) {

        System.out.print(text);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner inputI = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;

        while(true) {
            try {
                input = inputI.nextInt();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                scanInt(text);
            }
        }
        outputI = input;
    }
}
```

Being called(is that the right word? I'm new to java) by this class "Wow":

```java
public class Wow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScanInput numbers = new ScanInput();

        numbers.scanInt("INPUT NUMBERS: ");

        System.out.println("You entered: " + numbers.outputI);    
    }
}
```

I'm trying to have it repeat itself when an integer is not typed. If I type an integer the first time, it works and prints `"You entered: " + numbers.outputI`. If I do not, it does "INPUT NUMBERS: " again, but then it gets stuck in a loop and will just print `"You entered: " + numbers.outputI);` regardless of input. How do I get it to work if the first time is not an integer?

Comment: what's wrong with your current code? (what does it do and did you expect something different)

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere I honestly don't know. When it catches an exception, it loops back into that method but then it will not exit that method I guess. I want it to continue on to System.out.println("You entered: " + numbers.outputI) once an intiger has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `scanInt` from within `scanInt` is recursion, and recursion is one way to loop.

You *also* have a `while(true)` block; another loop. That's two loops. One loop too many. Remove one of these and you can make this work. Either one; your choice.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve your problem. The key point is you should use `inputI.next()` to clear the non-numeric strings in the buffer. Otherwise, `inputI.nextInt()` will keep throwing exception because failing to read int will not comsume the char of buffer.

```
public final void scanInt(String text) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner inputI = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input;

    while(true) {
        try {
            System.out.print(text);
            input = inputI.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            inputI.next();  // read the token does not match the Integer in buffer
        }
    }
    outputI = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another alternative. No **try/catch** required:

```
public int outputI;
private Scanner inputI = new Scanner(System.in);

public final void scanInt(String text) {
    String num = "";
    while(num.equals("")) {
        System.out.print(text);
        num = inputI.nextLine();
        // Is the entry a numerical string?
        if (!num.matches("\\d+")) {
            // No...
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Integer Number Only!");
            num = "";  // null string num so as to ensure another loop.
        }

    }
    // Convert string numerical value entry to Integer.
    this.outputI = Integer.parseInt(num);
}
```